# Ajax returns try/catch code instead of re-rendering the partial - Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rendering, try-catch, partial

Why am I getting a try/catch block, instead of re-rendering the partial, with the following code ?

VIEW:

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => { :controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'new_thing' } -%>

    [...whatever form code...]

    <%= submit_tag 'Continue' %>

<% end -%>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
def new_thing

  [...whatever controller code...]

  render :update do |page|
    page.replace_html "new", :partial => "new_thing"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy sh..., I'm sorry - Here's what was wrong:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

...was not included in the

```
<head></head>
```

tag.

Hope that will help the next n00b ;-)